OneClassSVM - How to solve the Warning of Scoring Failed
I'm building an OneClassSVM model, to detect image anomaly. I've extracted the image features with Resnet50, scale / PCA / fit my OCSMV model, and then I've got the following message:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:821: 
UserWarning: Scoring failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. 
Details: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 808, in _score
    scores = scorer(estimator, X_test)
TypeError: _BaseScorer.__call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_true'

I expect someone can help me
